# Raise Undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby

Ok i understand what is local variable and what is global variable, but i got into this exercise 40 on learnrubythehardway for extra credit where they ask to do each method on hash.

```
$cities = {"CA" => "San Francisco",
          "MI" => "Detroit",
          "FL" => "Jacksonville"}

#Adding a new kay with a new value
$cities["NY"] = "New York"
$cities["OR"] = "Portland"


def loop(map,state)

   $cities.each do |map,state|
         if map.include? state
            return map[state]

         else
            return "Not found."
         end
   end
end

$cities[:find] = method(:loop)

    while true

       print "State? (Enter to quit) "
       state = gets.chomp

       break if state.empty?

       #This line is the most important ever! study!
       puts $cities[:find].call(cities,state)
    end
```

The error is always giving me undefined local variable or method 'cities'

Anyway what i understand about local variable is that you can access those in the main file, but when it comes to global variable, you can assign it $ and access from the method inside itself.

I have research on other undefined variable or method, but theirs is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Suresh, can you provide a link to the question? Then I think someone can show/guide you to how to approach this problem the _Ruby Way_.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 the link is http://media.thebirn.com/webteam/LearnRubyTheHardWay.pdf, page 115 under extra credit

Answer (score 2):

This line is your problem:

```
puts $cities[:find].call(cities,state)
```

There is no local variable `cities` in scope, hence the error.

To be honest I find the whole example extremely contrived and pretty horrible. The times I actually needed global variables in the last 10+ years of writing Ruby can be counted on the fingers of one hand with some to spare.

Since you seem to be confused by global and local variables, have a look at this:

```
$foo = "foo"
defined?($foo)
#=> "global-variable"
defined?(foo)
#=> nil
```

This is what's happening in your example with `$cities` and `cities` (note the missing `$`).

Comment: Why need local variable, when i assign cities as $cities where you can access anyway you like?

Comment: I have no idea what that sentence is supposed to mean, but you're trying to access a local variable (`cities`) which doesn't exist. The only similarly named variable you have defined is the global `$cities`.

Comment: @Suresh I added an illustrative example for you.

Comment: but I did define all my $cities as global variable. Why are they still complaining?

Comment: You are trying to access a variable called `cities` though. Why do you expect that to exist? `$cities` and `cities` are two distinct variables. One is global, the other local, and they are not related to each other in any way.

Comment: `$cities[:find].call(**cities**,state)` — I added some emphasis around where you are trying to access the local variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: No problem :) If this solved your problem please mark the answer as accepted (the little tick mark below the vote count). And welcome to SO! :)

Comment: Apparently it still doesn't work at all even though i put the $cities. I try to change the cities to another name, still doesn't work, i think the cities is relying on the local variable. But the reason why i set the $cities to global variable is because i want to loop the ciities hash inside the loop method.

Comment: You can't just change it to another name. I suggest you study some more about variables and their scope, this discussion is not leading anywhere.

Comment: In that case, i can't solve the extra credit.  You did learnrubythehard as well?